# How can I count registers relationated?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table and I need a query that returns how many UPDATE's, INSERT's and DELETE's there are per tabla register.

[image]

Something like...

```
| Tabla  | # Of Insert's | # Of Delete's | # Of Update's
```

I don't know if it's clear, #NoEnglishNativeSpeaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
select
  Table,
  sum(case when Operacion = 'INSERT' then 1 else 0 end),
  sum(case when Operacion = 'DELETE' then 1 else 0 end),
  sum(case when Operacion = 'UPDATE' then 1 else 0 end)
from
  xxx
group by
  Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking out for something like this one:

```
select a.tabla,a.insertCount,b.updateCount,c.deleteCount
from (select
      Tabla,
      count(*) as insertCount
    from table
    where Operation = 'INSERT'
    group by
      Tabla)a,

(select
      Tabla,
      count(*) as insertCount
    from table
    where Operation = 'UPDATE'
    group by
      Tabla)b,

(select
      Tabla,
      count(*) as deleteCount
    from table
    where Operation = 'DELETE'
    group by
      Tabla)c
where a.tabla=b.tabla  and b.tabla=c.tabla
```